# Hermitian metric induces a volume form

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, metric-spaces

Given a hermitian metric on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb C$, what does it mean that his volume form is a given  $\omega$ ? Why does $SL(V)$ act transitively on the space $M_{\omega}(V)$ of hermitian metrics on $V$ with a given volume form $\omega$ ?

I don't know how to associate a volume form to a hermitian metric, and I can't guess which is the $SL(V)$ action we are talking about!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it suits your level. But you may want to check out this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_manifold .